# How to highlight a HTML block element or fade out the rest of the Page with Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css-transitions

I've just started building a web page help (highlighting + tutorial steps) jQuery plugin. You can see the latest result here.

http://goo.gl/ZZ2xy

My first try for highlighting is to have 4 overlay div's which are just moved around by css transition. It's simple but not perfect. It creates space lines between the overlay elements, in Chrome at least.

What would be the best way to create this animation?

Comment: You are seeing the gaps because of rounding errors in the animation (things can't be drawn at half a pixel,so they get rounded up or down.) You could try doing this with an SVG, then you can draw the right shape.

Comment: I would go with using one overlay plus html bloc that is copied on top of overlay. That would work unless you need to have this "window of focus" animation as in your example.

Comment: Also, have you tried moving them with transforms instead of absolute positioning? That might make a difference for no real reason!

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Especially the "difference for no real reason" part made me suspicious.
@WTK This could also work fine, but I'll stay with what I have now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got better solution for ya'. It's a proff-of-concept and definetly needs tweaking but in general it works. The idea is to use table 3x3 as overlay, use semi-transparent background for all cells except for one that is suppose to work as a window through which you're looking at target html element.

I imagine there may be some quirks with browsers (probably fixable) but it's still cleaner and nicer option than one you're using right now.

The example code is available here http://jsbin.com/ekijev/4

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is nicer and cleaner. But I'm not yet sure wether I like the solution more for my plugin cause it has the disadvantage that the highlighted block is not clickable anymore?!
Yes I've missed that requirement in the first post, sry. And thanks again for the example!

Comment: If it's suppose to be clickable (and usable - forms inputs etc) then yeah, it might be a little problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery .css() method right improved the thing a lot. Still sometimes a white line but it's ok for me. It's allready updated at github.

**Old:**

```
$elem.css({"left" : x})
   .css({"top" : y}) 
   .width(width)
   .height(height);
```

**New**

```
$elem.css({
            "left" : x,
            "top" : y,
            "width" : width,
            "height" : height
});
```

Answer (score -1):

so i have a fade solution for you. just the basics but should be enough to help you out.

just paste the code into a notepad file save and run

**CODE UPDATED**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
    DIV{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .black{
        background:black;
    }
    .yellow{
        background:yellow;
    }
    .red{
        background:red;
    }
    .green{
        background:green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="1" class="yellow"></div>
        <div id="2" class="black"></div>
        <div id="3" class="red"></div>
        <div id="4" class="green"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function (){
        var target = 2;//id of element we dont want faded
        var pageElements = $('#container').find('*').toArray();//get all elements in our container
        for(var counter = 0; counter < pageElements.length;counter++){//itterate through them
            if(pageElements[counter].id != target){//if element is not our target fade
                $(pageElements[counter]).fadeOut("slow",OnFadeComplete);//fade

            }
        }
    });

    function OnFadeComplete(){
        $(this).attr('style','visibility:hidden;');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I'm correct, your code would hide anything except one element. That would totaly messed up the layout, most of the times woudn't work at all and that's not what OP asked for.

Comment: please see updated code. all i did was use visibility style insted of display:none style